# jQuery - Click link based on css class and name of link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to have jQuery find the text of an object and then find the link before it and then click it? I have this example where I want jQuery to click on either of the 2 links below:

```
<tr>
    <td nowrap="true" width="170" valign="top">
         <div class="float-left">
<b><a href="javascript:GoToETURL('/url-example-1.html','business');">1234 Account</a></b>
<br>
<span style="display:none" class="fullaccnum">1234</span>
         </div>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td nowrap="true" width="170" valign="top">
        <div class="float-left">
<b><a href="javascript:GoToETURL('/url-example-2.html','business');">5678 Account</a></b>
<br>
<span style="display:none" class="fullaccnum">5678</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is my jQuery that I'm using currently and it works but what happens if the order of the accounts above gets sorted differently then it will click on the wrong link for the wrong account:

```
if(account_id == '1234'){
    jQuery(".float-left b a")[0].click(); //click on first href
} else {
    jQuery(".float-left b a")[1].click(); //click on second href
}
```

So is it possible for jQuery to do something like this:

```
if(account_id == '1234'){
    //find span class='fullaccnum' where span equals 1234
    //found match, go back up the tree and click href
    jQuery(".float-left b a").click();
    //goes to 'url-example-1.html'
} else {
    //find span class='fullaccnum' where span equals 5678
    //found match, go back up the tree and click href
    jQuery(".float-left b a").click();
    //goes to '/url-example-2.html'
}
```

Comment: This is an odd workflow.  What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?  From where is the account_id variable generated?

Answer (score 1):

try to use this function

```
 function clickonanchor(text){
       $('tr').each(function(){
          var spantext = $(this).find('.fullaccnum').text();
          if (spantext == text){
               $(this).find('.float-left > b > a').click();
          }
       });    
    }
```

and use it

```
clickonanchor('1234');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if the text inside span doesn't change and will be what you have given!!

```
function checkclick(accNo) //Call this function wherever you want and pass Account_ID
{
     $('div.float-left span.fullaccnum').each(function(){
           if(accNo==$(this).html())
           {
               $(this).siblings('b').children('a').trigger('click')
           }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to play with jquery closest() api you will get the desired results.
Below is a small snippet of it:

```js
$('.fullaccnum').closest('b a').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assume that account_id is automatically generated or came from database or something else. Here is the solutions :

```
var account_id  = 1234;
$('.fullaccnum:contains("'+account_id+'")').closest('.float-left').find('a').click();
```

No matter what number account_id was generated, then it will find out the matched element using [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

Comment: would it be easier if we used the text between the href? So Link 1 = account_id 1234 and Link 2 equals account_id 5678. I think that might easier if I can get it to work

Comment: Not sure to do that because, the text inside a link is different with account id. If you set already something like `<a href="url">1234</a>`, then of course it can.

Comment: if that is the case, do you have an example of how that could work?

Comment: just modified code above something like `$('.float-left a:contains("'+account_id+'")').click();` , not sure if this what you want.

Comment: I see. I tried this with no luck: jQuery(".float-left b a:contains('Link 1')").click();

Comment: Why you search for "Link 1"? Can you share complete code you made for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76407/discussion-between-chad-priddle-and-norlihazmey-ghazali).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','.float-left',function(){
    var account_id = $(this).find('a').text();
    if(account_id == '1234'){
   $(this).find('a').trigger('click'); 
 } else {
   $(this).parents('tr').next('tr').find('a').trigger('click');
 }
})
```

try this.